# Symbolic link for Wordpress Theme

Tags: linux, wordpress, symlink

i have multiple sites (30) on my VPS with the same template into the /wp-content/themes/ directory and when i have to update the theme i have to do the operation on thirty folders.

It's possible to link with a Symbolic Lynk to the folder of the theme into the /wp-content/themes/ directories?

I want to do something like this if it's possible:

```
/var/www/<theme_folder>/ -> /home/<user>/public_html/wp-content/themes/<link_theme_folder>
```

Can wordpress recognize the folder with a "special" Sym Link?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad English.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

I tried locally and WordPress 4.x did not detect the symlinked folder, so I guess it's a no-go.

What you should consider is migrate your 30 WP installations into [one multisite (or "network") configuration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).
This will allow you to centralize plugins and themes for all your websites in one interface to rule them all.

You will need to organize the migration:
- setup a new WP, configure it as multisite.
- all plugins used by all of your 30 sites should be imported into this Wordpress, along with their configurations (I'd do that manually);
- Add your Theme to the themes folder;
- recreate the users;
- export the posts from each site as an xml file;
- import each xml file to its related new blog;
- You will need a Domain mapping plugin so that each blog has its own Domain name. (site1.com, site2.com instead of site.com/site1/ urls).

**Tips:**

1. Tell your customers that you need to "freeze" their websites for the necessary time (meaning: no more touching the CMS, adding posts, changing configurations).
2. Practice on a local copy first to play around first.
3. Work on another, separate, domain name during the setup. When the sites are all properly replicated, update the DNS registry of the 30 sites to point to the new multisite WP. This way, no downtime!

This can take some time but will make it much easier for management and for adding new sites in the future.